# JavaFX- Don't scale image for stage icon?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am setting an image to my Stage so that becomes the logo for the JavaFX application.

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("myLogo.png"));
```

However, the image gets scaled and stretched horizontally since it is not at a ratio it likes.

Is there a way can manipulate the image so it is centered in its placement, or add margins so it matches the expected ratio?

I don't want to create a whole new image if I can help it.

Comment: I think the dimension for icons is a standard size. So you may edit your image to have extra transparent edges.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping to hear... but okay. Unless someone else has an idea.